# How to copy cell format while save workbook?

Tags: python-3.x

here is my code,basically just write data into a xlsm template: [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRaCD.png)

```
def writeIntoTemplate(data, fileName):
 fn = fileName.split('.')
 base_dir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\finalResult'  # store result
 path = os.path.join(base_dir, fn[0]+'.xlsm')

 df = data
 TemplateFileName = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\template2.xlsm"
 wb = xl.load_workbook(TemplateFileName, keep_vba=True)
 ws = wb.active
 mr = df.shape[0]
 mc = df.shape[1]
 for i in range(1, mr + 1):
    for j in range(1, mc + 1):
        ws.cell(row=i+2, column=j).value = df.iloc[i-1][j-1]
 wb.save(filename=path)
```

however the font color in [G1] and [h1] become all black, how can i fix the format to show the right color such as the template ?

thank you for your help

Comment: What library are you using to access the workbook?

Comment: import openpyxl as xl